# How to pass a folder of images to a dog classification CNN model for training using tensorflow?

Tags: image, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a folder of 10000 images of 120 different breeds of [dogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLPfh.jpg) with each individual image having a unique id example: 000bec180eb18c7604dcecc8fe0dba07 and each such id has a corresponding label name in another CSV file. What should I do to pass these images in mini-batches to a CNN?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/DirectoryIterator). But before using it you'll need to preprocess your images so that each category will have its own directory.
Preprocess step will something be like follows

```
1. Get name for each file in the folder.
2. For each file, look up its category in the csv
   add it to a maintained list of category files
3. Create sub-directory for each category
4. Move the files in their respective directory
5. Now use the `DirectoryIterator`
```